# Embed images after query results are returned using R, Shiny, DT and DBI

Tags: r, image, shiny, dbi, dt

I'm creating a Data Table in R Shiny that gets populated by a SELECT statement that pulls from a table in SSMS. One of the columns returns the text of an image located in the www folder where R pulls from. For example, if my query was:

```sql
SELECT Fruit, Image, Description
FROM tblFruit
```

It may return something like this in SQL:

```
Fruit  |  Image      |  Description
-----------------------------------
apple  |  apple.png  |  red apple
orange |  orange.png |  orange orange
banana |  banana.png |  yellow banana
```

My Data Table in R resembles just that, but my goal is to replace the text "apple.png" with the actual image that lives in the www folder. Is this possible?

Here's a mock up/snippet of what my app.R looks like :

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(RJDBC)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
library(shinyBS)

conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLServer;databaseName=DEV", Sys.getenv("userid"), Sys.getenv("pwd"))

sqlSelect = trimws("SELECT Fruit, Image, Description FROM tblFruit ")
sqlWhere = "WHERE Fruit in ('Apple','Orange','Banana')"

body <- dashboardBody(class="text-center",
                        tabItem("fruit", class ="text-center",
                                fluidRow(
                                  tabBox(title = "Fruit", id = "FruitID",
                                         tabPanel(title = 'Fruit',
                                                  fluidRow(
                                                    box(width=12,
                                                        div(DT::dataTableOutput(outputId = "DT_Fruit"), style="font-size:125%", class ="text-left")
                                                    )
                                                  )
                                         )
                                  ) # tabBox
                                ) # fluidRow
                        ) # tabItem fruit
                      ) # tabItems
) # body

server <- function(input, output){
    output$DT_Fruit <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(options = list(dom = 't'), rowname = FALSE, dbGetQuery(conn, paste(sqlSelect, sqlWhere)))
    })
}
```

Edit: Per the first comment here, I'm not having issues reading from the www folder. I'm wanting to replace the text (ex. "apple.png") returned from my query with an image named apple.png from the www folder. I'm more or less looking for direction/advice on how to best approach this.

Comment: It seems like you're only having problem displaying local image in a datatable. Possible duplicate of [Display Image in a Data Table from a local path in R Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370227/display-image-in-a-data-table-from-a-local-path-in-r-shiny)

Comment: Yifu Yan, thank you for your reply but maybe I didn't describe my issue well enough. I've added an Edit to the bottom for further clarification and unfortunately the link you provided is not the same as my issue/question.

Comment: I read your updated question. What do you men by `returns a image named app`? Do you want to return copies of image binary file or just have images displayed in the table?

Comment: Yes, have images displayed in the data table. Leaving what I have right now simply returns the text "apple.png" in the Image column. The desired outcome is to actually have the image displayed.

Comment: In order to make the images displayed in the table, you need to convert them into HTML `img` tags, please see my answer below.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying and am familiar with this approach, but not sure how to convert the results returned from my query and connect them to the images. The columns and data in my data table is dynamic in that it queries a database. Regardless, I'll take what you've posted and try to work that into my code.

Comment: I see what you mean. So the images are stored in database and not publicly available. So I guess what you can do is download the images from database first.

Comment: The image itself is not stored in the database, only the image name - "apple.png".

Comment: So where are those images stored? If they are in a different directory, you can use something like. `paste0("path/to/your/image/","apple.png")`

Comment: The images are stored in the www folder. How would you incorporate your data.frame into my dbGetQuery() in my output?

Comment: I don't understand why you are having issues on this. Files in www can be used in HTML as if they are in root folder.

Comment: Please check shiny cheatsheet: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/cheatsheet.html

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my issue... but thank you for trying. Maybe re-reading my post would better clarify what my goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
render <- c(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
  "  if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var img = '<img src= \"' + data + '\">';",
  "    return img;",
  "  }else{",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)
```

and in `server`:

```
output$DT_Fruit <- renderDT({
  datatable(
    dbGetQuery(conn, paste(sqlSelect, sqlWhere)), 
    rownames = FALSE, 
    options = list(
      dom = "t",
      columnDefs = list(
        list(targets = 1, render = JS(render))
      )
    )
  )
})
```

Comment: BINGO! Thank you very much. Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It still seems like you are having issue displaying images in DT table, if that's your question.

Convert `apple.png` to a `img` tag in HTML using `glue::glue()` or `paste0()`, and set `escapse = FALSE` so DT will parse it as HTML.

Please see the example below, just replace value in `src` with your image path.

```
library(DT)
DT::datatable(
    data.frame(
        images = c(
            "<img src='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81xQBb5jRzL._SY355_.jpg' alt='apple.jpg' width='100px'>",
            "<img src='https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71gI-IUNUkL._SL1500_.jpg' alt='banana.jpg' width='100px'>"
        )
    ),escape = FALSE
)
```